# XMLHttpRequest + FormData file upload not working in Chrome with "large" files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, file-upload

I've added a file upload utility for a internal application at my company. It works fine for all the folks that are in an office with fast internet. It also works for users who prefer Internet Explorer and it even works when the files are very small for users who use Chrome. It doesn't work at all with the file is larger than 50k AND the browser is Chrome AND the connection is slow. Files that are 10k-20k seem to work fine.

After pressing upload (by a user in the not working group) the process is kicked and after 2 mins the network tab (in Chrome) has a status of (failed) net::err_Unexpected. The Response tab says "Failed to load Response Data". There are no server messages.

I've tested all different file sizes (up to 5000k) in Internet Explorer and they seem to work fine.

```
function uploadFile(file, url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fd = new FormData();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            numQueuedFilesCount++;
            // Every thing ok, file uploaded
            updateAttachmentList();
        } else if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            // with some error
            console.log(xhr.responseText); // handle response.
        }
    };
    fd.append("uploadfile", file);
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Comment: Does it happen across different operating systems?

Comment: How slow is the Internet connection?

Comment: @Barmar We only use Windows. The internet connection is about 5 Mbps

Comment: That's not very slow, it's pretty good upload speed for consumer broadband Internet in the US. 50k should take about 0.1 sec to transfer at that rate. Have you tried doing a packet capture to see what's being sent, whether there are excessive timeouts and retransmissions?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry the 5Mbps is the DOWNLOAD speed. I should have reported the upload speed, which is 500 Kbps. Still fast enough.

Comment: Yeah, it should take about a second to upload the file, it doesn't seem like the browser should time out in that time. Try the packet capture to see what's happening.

Comment: @Barmar Still not sure what's going on but I did have a new development. I installed Fiddler on the remote users machine and it always works with Fiddler open!

Comment: Fiddler is a proxy, so it could be affecting the way the file is sent. Try something lower level like Wireshark.